# Can't update OxyPlot graph after initialisation

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I have a a OxyPlot chart definied in my XAML like this:

```
<oxy:Plot Height="336">
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Chart}"/>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

In the viewModel I have the following:

```
public ObservableCollection<DataPoint> Chart { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    Chart = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>() 
            { new DataPoint(12, 14), new DataPoint(20, 26) };

    public void PriceChange(Model[] quotes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < quotes.Length; i++)         
        {
            Chart.Add(new DataPoint(quotes[i].LastTradePrice, i*10));          
        }
    }
}
```

I can see the initial graph drawn for the initial two hardcoded `DataPoint`s.

But after everything is up and the `PriceChange()` method is firing, the new `DataPoint`s aren't drawn on the chart.  Since it's an `ObservableCollection` it should notify the UI automatically, shouldn't it?  Or what am I missing?

BTW I have following this [example](http://oxyplot.org/doc/HelloWpfXaml.html) on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `Chart` ObservableCollection will be providing appropriate notifications, I don't think the chart/plot itself will necessarily be responding to those notifications, so it may well not know it needs to be redrawn.

I'm not familiar with OxyPlot, but I had a quick crack at following a tutorial, and from a quick scan of the `Plot` class, I found a method called `InvalidatePlot()`, which seems to force the plot to redraw itself - it may well be the case that you need to call that if you're intend on making changes to the plot data. It certainly worked when I tried it in a small sample project.

I didn't find a huge amount of example usage, however these links may help:

http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/398856

http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/discussions/352003

And this is the example referred to in the second of those links:

http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Examples/WPF/WpfExamples/Examples/CoupledAxesDemo/

Edit:

It looks like the intended approach may well be to create a `PlotModel` and bind the `Model` property of your plot to it, you can then notify the UI when the `PlotModel` changes:

oxyplot.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Source/Examples/WPF/WpfExamples/Examples/RealtimeDemo/

Comment: Its quite strange, how it works. I needed to look at `RefreshDemo` example to figure it out. Its the only demo that uses multithreading. How they do that is to set a strange `RefreshFlag` like this: `<o:Plot RefreshFlag="{Binding Refresh}">
            <o:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Points}"/>
        </o:Plot>` to actually refresh it. Feels hacky, but it works. :)

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a much better approach, you could even put it as an answer, good job =D

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
<oxy:Plot InvalidateFlag="{Binding DataPoints.Count, Delay=20}">
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding DataPoints}"/>
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
</oxy:Plot>
```

In your case the Delay is not needed but it can be useful at times.